# Find/replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to do a find replace of an entire database in MySQL, without having to actually script it in a language (I mean, if that's what has to be done, so be it).

Basically I want to replace a site name, with another site name (I'm setting up a dev server for upgrades) in Drupal.

My thoughts are that all links in the database need to be changed. I would prefer to use PHPMyAdmin to do this, but I'm happy to use the command line as well.

Comment: Are you trying to find/replace in a single table/column, or do you want to search ever table/column in the entire database?

Comment: Every table/column in the entire database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table setup like:

```
sites
    site_id
    url
```

You could use [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) in an `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE sites SET url=REPLACE(url, 'findUrl.com', 'replaceUrl.com');
```

**UPDATE:** To support the need to "find & replace" on every column in every table in a given database, a [`Stored Procedure`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) is required (if you want to do it directly in MySQL, of course). Here's a rough-draft ***(untested)*** of what could do it:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `find_replace_in_all_tables`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE TABLE_NAME CHAR(255);
    DECLARE COLUMN_NAME CHAR(255);

    DECLARE tables CURSOR for 
        SELECT table_name, column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN tables;
    WHILE done = 0 DO
        FETCH NEXT FROM tables INTO TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;

        IF done = 0 THEN
            SET @SQL_TEXT = CONCAT("UPDATE `", TABLE_NAME, "` SET `", COLUMN_NAME, "`=REPLACE(`", COLUMN_NAME, "`, 'findUrl.com', 'replaceUrl.com');");

            PREPARE statement FROM @SQL_TEXT;
            EXECUTE statement;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE tables;
END
```

The stored procedure iterates through the [`information_schema`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) database for every table/column in your current database. With this list, it builds an `UPDATE` query similar to my original answer and executes it. This could be made more efficient if you limit the column-types in the `SELECT` query, or if you know the exact column names the replacement can take place on (but I guess then you wouldn't need to do a find+replace.